# Elastic search suggest action doesn't return all possible suggestions

Tags: elasticsearch

Seems like elastic suggest option doesn't return me what i expected. I guess it's about bad params but i don't see it.

If body contains word like "TOURNAMENT" and if i run suggest api for "TOURNAME" i got "TOURNAMENT" as suggestion. But if i run same api for "TOURNA" i don't get "TOURNAMENT" as suggestion.

EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:

```
{
    "size": 0,
     "suggest" : {
          "my-sugg": {
              "text" : "TOURNAME",
               "term": {
                  "field" : "body",
                   "min_word_length" : "3"

             }
        }
     }
}
```

I got expected result

```
"my-sugg": [
            {
                "text": "tourname",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 8,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "tournament",
                        "score": 0.75,
                        "freq": 60
                    }
                ]
            }
```

NOT EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:

If i run exactly the same api as above with

```
  "my-sugg": {
          "text" : "TOURNA":




"suggest": {
        "my-sugg": [
            {
                "text": "tourna",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 6,
                "options": [
                    {
                        "text": "tour’s",
                        "score": 0.6666666,
                        "freq": 5
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "tour's",
                        "score": 0.6666666,
                        "freq": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "tour",
                        "score": 0.5,
                        "freq": 34
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "turn",
                        "score": 0.5,
                        "freq": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I got wrong result. I would like to get "tournament' as one possible suggestion. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mixing up the [term suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-suggesters-term.html) with the [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/search-suggesters-completion.html).

The first one allows you to do something like `did you mean` functionality, suggesting similar terms, where as the second allows you to implement `search as you type` functionality. I think this is what you are after here.